# List Comprehension Python Prime numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I came across a solution on Stack Overflow to generate prime numbers using list comprehension. But was unable to understand what does the inner for loop do.

I have tried something like

```
[x for x in range(5,20) for y in range(2,int(x/2)+1) if any(x%y == 0)]
```

It throws an error: 'bool' object is not iterable

I know that my syntax is wrong but logically for prime numbers we have a for loop followed by a for loop and then a if condition to calculate remainder(x%y).
But the answer on Stack Overflow is

```
[x for x in range(2, 20) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]
```

I understood the reason why all is used, but I am unable to get how the condition inside all() is working as ideally for should be following if so that range(2,x) is iterated and y gets values which are in turn used for computing(x%y). How can y be used even before it is has been assigned a value.

Comment: `x` and `y` are not iterables, they are single integers. `any` requires an iterable such as a generator expression or a list. Besides, the logic in your attempt would leave **non-prime** integers.

Comment: Agreed but why  x%y!=0 does not throw an error even if y gets a value after its value has been used.And  for prime numbers we have a for loop followed by a for loop and then a if condition to calculate remainder(x%y). Unable to understand the execution of all()@meowgoesthedog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just the wonderful thing about list comprehension if it can work normally like the `for` loop, people wont create it because the `for` loop is more readable and understandable.

You may find out that the result of list comprehension is always a `list`, meanwhile the result of `for` loop would always many single values and these single values is a part of `iterable`

> [x +1 for x in range(1,5)]
> [2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> for x in range (1,10):    print(x+1)
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5

You can simply understand that the loop comprehension already have the list of values, then they just simply feed orderly to the condition value by value. Like this:

> [1+1 , 2+1 , 3+1 , 4+1]

Your code is wrong because you inherit too much from the ordinary `for` loop. Your code written in for loop would be like this:

```
for x in range(5,20):
    for y in range(2,int(x/2)+1):
        if any(x%y == 0):
            print(x)
```

And the result would obviously:

> TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

because `any` requires an iterable such as a generator expression or a `**list**` as mentioned above by **@meowgoesthedog** . Coincidentally, list is just all about list comprehension. However, you need comprehend it in order to utilize the list comprehension well. It sometimes happens to me too, in your case, the `for y in range(2,int(x/2)+1)` works as a normal `for` loop.

This is the syntax of list comprehension.
[image]

In side the condition `if` which is optional predicate. We can create another list comprehension by following the rules with `x%y==0` is output expression and a variable `y` representing members of the input sequence `range(2,int(x/2)+1)`

Comment: List comprehension is more readable if you have encountered mathematical set-builder notation which it is based off.

Comment: Also, every list comprehension can very much be written as a for loop

Answer (score 2):

`all()` and `any()` works on itterable objects. For example `all([True, True, False, True])` returns `False`. You cant use `any(True)` (like in your example: `any(x%y == 0)`)

This statement `[x for x in range(2, 20) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]` can be translated to this code:

```
res = []
for x in range(2, 20):
    temporary_list = (x%y != 0 for y in range(2,x))
    if all(temporary_list):
        res.append(x)
```

Ps. I saw in comments that you are not sure how `y` is declared. In python, there are more great structures than list of comprehension. One of them is generator of comprehension - I believe it is used in this case.

Comment: How did you translate that code. I mean could you share some resources.

Comment: I know it from my experience. Just read about lists of comprehension. Once you get familiar with them it will be much easier to understand code like this.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `all` and `any` work on iterable objects (list, sets, etc). Therefore you get an error when you apply it on boolean - `x%y==0`.

You can use any in the following manner -

`[x for x in range(5,20) if not any([x % y == 0 for y in range(2, int(x/2)+1)])]`

or -

```
[x for x in range(2, 20) if not any(x % y == 0 for y in range(2, int(x/2)+1))]
```

As any and all **complement** each other.